# How to write log to differnt logfile in one process use GLOG

Tags: glog

when I used GLog for logfile, I want to write my glog file to differnt logfile like log4j,but It seems like that the Glog don't support this, How can I do and can I init two glog in one function, please help

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions.

1. Glog support user defined logger. You can implement your own logger like below.

```
class AsyncLogger : public google::base::Logger
```

2. You can pass some flag in message and then store the log to the corresponding file according to the flag.

```
void AsyncLogger::Write(bool force_flush, time_t timestamp, const char* message,
                        int message_len) {
        int flag = GetFlag(message);
        string file_= file_name + flag + ".txt";
        fwrite(message, 1, message_len, file_);
}
```

3. Create macro definition and add flag to message

```
#define ALOG_MODULE_STREAM_INFO(module)                         \
  google::LogMessage(__FILE__, __LINE__, google::INFO).stream() \
      << flag << ","
```

3. And then set the logger to glog

```
google::base::SetLogger(FLAGS_minloglevel, async_logger);
```